# Jquery Load() wont work (not href # , JSON, or some syntax error I believe)

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

```
function load_contents(e){
  document.getElementById('profile-tab-contents').innerHTML += '<br>Some new content!';
  $('#profile-tab-contents').load('http://jsonview.com/example.json'); --This LINE does not work
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("active");


  x[0].className = "";

  document.getElementById("e").className = "active";


}
```

Called it with:

```
<li role="presentation" id="awards-tab"><a href="#" onclick="load_contents(this)">Awards</a></li>
```

I named it properly:

```
<div id="profile-tab-contents">            
        </div>
```

Only Frameworks linked:

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I tried the other examples posted here but it doesn't work and I dont know why .

Please help thanks.

Comment: check your dev tools (F12), see if you're getting a CORS error...

Comment: Okay I'll do it in a sec, apparently adding "some new content!" works so im guessing its just some jquery problem

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://jsonview.com/example.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. I tried it with my own html on my computer and it didn't work also

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/shimao/Desktop/getit/public/sample-portfolio.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Yep. This is a newer technology called CORS (cross-origin resource sharing). It allows websites to prevent calls to their files unless the calls are allowed through (via an API and key usually). You can sometimes get around this with jsonp requests for JSON files. Check here for more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS  or here for more on jsonp with CORS: https://dev.socrata.com/docs/cors-and-jsonp.html